# What kind of batteries are allowed to be transported?

Tags: safety, battery

I am based out of India and I have to send two mobile phones along with batteries to Japan.  I thought of sending it by DHL.  [This link](http://www.dhl.co.in/en/express/shipping/shipping_advice/lithium_batteries.html) gives information about regulations regarding the batteries.

I want to know whether the following batteries if put inside the phones and discharged is acceptable for courier or not:

[image]

[image]

A relevant paragraph at the end of the linked article is:

> Due to the fact that PI965 is forbidden on passenger aircraft we offer
>   a limited service. PI965 Section II requires separate dangerous goods
>   account approval, since April 2016. For additional information please
>   contact your local DHL representative. Lithium ion batteries packed
>   with equipment (PI966) or contained in equipment (PI967) are
>   acceptable for transport.

Does that mean if I pack the batteries inside the phones it is acceptable ?

Comment: To the OP: this seems to be more a passenger-side question, and we generally treat those as off-topic, since they are better handled on Travel.SE, see: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/42411/26630

Comment: Hazardous Materials Regulations and handling is very much a part of the aviation transportation industry. This question does not appear to be about the passenger transportation aspect of hazardous materials (spare batteries are generally allowed in carry-on luggage only) but about the cargo shipment of batteries. That being said, I'm not sure that general HMR should really be on topic for this exchange. I am voting to close as this question is only tangentially aviation related. Legal might be a better place to ask.

Comment: Why don't you ask to DHL?

Comment: @mins they gave me the above link